Meta WhatsApp Business Signup and Webhook
My team is setting up Embedded Signup Login for WhatsApp Business by Meta. Now, we are having multiple clients who would get onboarded via the ES setup. So, whenever any client finishes signup, a webhook is triggered by Meta to send the WABA ID and the phone number. Yet, my team is having difficulty understanding which WABA ID is related to which client.
For the same, I wanted to understand if we could send any custom identifiers inside the Facebook Login JAVA SDK which can be received in pingback from webhook?
Or how to handle the identification of WABA ID to my onboarded client ID?
We have tried exploring custom parameters in JSON for Facebook JAVASDK but have not found any resources that could help.
